# AngularJs. Using defer in module

Tags: module, angularjs, deferred

I have custom module that get data from api.
it's async, so i use defer for it.

```
angular.module('module', []).factory('api', function($q){
    var $scope;
    return {
        setScope: function(scope){ $scope = scope; },
        getPic:function(){
            var def = $q.defer();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/shaverm/picture?redirect=false',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function(r){
                    def.resolve(r.data.url);
                    $scope.$apply();
                },
            });
            return def.promise
        }
    }
});
```

It works fine, but i'm worrying about using scope.$apply in the module.

Here is example http://jsfiddle.net/mfbFs/

Can it be improved?

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using jQuery's ajax, when Angular comes with it and has a built-in promise?

```js
angular.module('module', []).factory('api', function($http){
  return {
    getPic: function(){
      return $http.jsonp('https://graph.facebook.com/shaverm/picture?redirect=false&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK');
    }
  };
});
```

Much simpler! And no need to worry about the digest - your controller will already ensure that happens when it should.

Comment: In simple case your variant is great, but i have complex system, so i should do it manually. I used $.ajax just for show you what i mean. But thanks for note

Comment: @unlimited No, you really shouldn't. :-) Can you elaborate on your complex use case?

Comment: There are sub queries which modify the data from top query. And defer resolves when all sub queries are completed

Comment: @unlimited You can do subqueries using the promise. You can chain `then` calls against it. You can also use `$q.all([promise1, promise2, promise3], callback)` to combine all your promises into one promise.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set the `$scope` before calling the API, just inject the `$rootScope` on the service and call `$apply()` (or `$digest()`) on that scope, like this:

```
angular.module('module', []).factory('api', function($q, $rootScope){
    return {           
        getPic:function(){
            var def = $q.defer();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/shaverm/picture?redirect=false',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function(r){
                    def.resolve(r.data.url);
                    $rootScope.$apply();
                },
            });
            return def.promise
        }
    }
});
function demoCtrl ($scope, api){         
     $scope.url = api.getPic();   
}
```